# Show ListBox Items One By One (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-silverlight

I have a `ListBox`, a Show `Button`, and a `TextBlock` in my Windows Phone application.

Whenever the user clicks on the Show `Button`, an item from the `ListBox` 
should be shown in `TextBlock`. If the user clicks on Show `Button` again, the next item should be shown.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="FavoriteListBox"  
         SelectionChanged="FavoriteListBox_SelectionChanged"                         
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomListBoxItemStyle}"
         Height="300" Width="250">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock x:Name="FavoriteListBoxTextBlock" 
                        FontSize="40" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                        Text="{Binding AnswerName}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<TextBlock x:Name="DisplayTextBlock"/>

<Button x:Name="ShowButton" Click="ShowButton_Click"/>
```

**C#**

```
private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FavoriteListBox != null)
     {
          // ??????
     }
}
```

How can achieve such functionality?

Comment: hey! there is one answer which is not visible now, but not work
int currentListIndex = 0;
 if (FavoriteListBox.Items.Count <= currentListIndex)
  {
         DisplayTextBlock.Text = FavoriteListBox.Items[currentListIndex++].ToString();                  
                }
                else
                {                   
                    currentListIndex = 0;
                    DisplayTextBlock.Text = FavoriteListBox.Items[0].ToString();
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be quite easily using indices directly.

Suppose the list you use for the `ListBox` items is called `listobj`, then you can use the following:

```
private int _displayedFavoriteIndex = -1;

private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //move to the next item
    _displayedFavoriteIndex++;    
    if ( _displayedFavoriteIndex >= listobj.Count )
    {
        //we have reached the end of the list
        _displayedFavoriteIndex = 0;
    }
    //show the item
    DisplayTextBlock.Text = listobj[ _displayedFavoriteIndex ].AnswerName;
}
```

**Note** you don't have to check whether `FavoriteListBox` is `null`, because such situation will never happen - all controls are initialized with the `InitializeComponent` call in the constructor.

Comment: Okay Your Note also very helpful Thanks you ;)

Comment: one last thing when i add -- in place of ++ what should i need to do in if condition

Comment: If you want to go backwards, you will have to check if `_displayedFavoriteIndex <= 0` and then inside the block you will have to set `_displayedFavoriteIndex = listobj.Count - 1` :-)